# appending to a dataframe that is indexed by datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a DataFrame indexed by datetime, created like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20140101',periods=1)
record = pd.DataFrame(index=dates,columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
```

I'd like to add rows to the record with a simple function, addrowfunc, called like this:

```
addrowfunc('2012-01-01',1,2,3)
```

with the addrowfunc that does something like this:

```
def addrowfunc(newdate,dat1,dat2,dat3)
   newRow = pd.DataFrame([dict(col1=dat1,col2=dat2,col3=dat3)])     
   record.append(newRow,ignore_index=False)
   print(p.record) #print the appended record to the console
```

however, this doesn't insert newdate into the newRow of the DataFrame as the index of the appended record.  How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function wrapper is just unneccessary overhead, I would do it like this.

```
>>> record.loc['2014-01-02'] = np.array([dat1, dat2, dat3])
>>> record
Out[26]: 
                    col1 col2 col3
2014-01-01 00:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
2014-01-02             1    2    3
```